# Change package version for php service without modifying composer.lock

Tags: php, continuous-integration, composer-php, continuous-deployment

I'd like to ask some another newbie questions about Composer/CI/CD.

But what if I need to make a build with different package version but I can't change `composer.lock` in the repository. What instrument should I better use for this task?

Thank you in advance!

Maybe it's better to have another branch with another `composer.lock` for each different configuration task? Because it's better to test dependencies before build?

Sincerely,

gtw000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`composer.json` is your ingredients list; `composer.lock` is your ingredients list for your secret recipe. One is generic, the other is specific.

If you are wanting to test out a different package version, your `composer.lock` file will get updated; it has to, no choice. However, you are correct that you will want to create a branch of your project to test this out.

Look for a [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/CHANGELOG-4.1.md) or an [UPGRADE](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-4.1.md) in the package's repo or in their documents. If you are lucky, that repo has instructions and caveats for upgrading the package.

If it's a patch update, test it. If it's a minor upgrade, test it. If it's a major upgrade, test the heck out of it. This is an example of where having good unit and integration tests comes in handy. If you don't know how to tell if it's a patch, minor, or major upgrade, check out [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/).

Have fun!